# Custom action with javascript doesn't navigate in DisplayForm

Tags: 2007, development, custom-actions

I have a strange issue, basically, I have the following custom action:

```
 <CustomAction
      Id="Navigate.DisplayMenu"
      Title="Navigate to:"
      RegistrationType="ContentType"
      RegistrationId="0x010100AEAD1A170E39D343BE3252ECF5B97"
      GroupId="ActionsMenu"
      Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
      Sequence="100">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:window.location='{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Pages/InterPage.aspx?listid={ListId}&amp;itemid={ItemId}&amp;source='+window.location" />
  </CustomAction>
```

Based on content type this custom action appears in DisplayForm, but the problem is when i click it, it does'nt redicrect to another "InterPage.aspx", the page just refreshes and that is it ...

Any idea what the problem could be?

Note: it is for sharepoint 2007

Comment: Its seem to work on 2010.strange issue in 2007. but can you try this : `<UrlAction Url="javascript:void(window.location.href='{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Pages/InterPage.aspx?listid={ListId}&amp;itemid={ItemId}&amp;source='+window.location)" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue having the following url:

```
 <UrlAction Url="javascript:function GoToUrl(){var site='{SiteUrl}';var item='{ItemId}';var list='{ListId}';window.location.href=site+'/_layouts/Pages/InterPage.aspx?list='+list+'&amp;ID='+item};GoToUrl();return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.loaction.href in UrlAction for redirecting.

Comment: i tried, but it is still the same behaviour :( no success

Comment: When you click on that button, there is no change in your page URL right? It means UrlAction is not called. Else if changed try navigating to any test page.

Comment: Try this..<UrlAction Url="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank'))"/>

Comment: Oh, yes, this does work!, but yea again it opens a new window but i have to redirect on current

Comment: Then use _self instead of _blank.

Comment: no, doesn't work, if i change to _self it just stays on the same page, this is so broken really :(

Comment: Check this..<UrlAction Url="javascript:window.location='{SiteUrl}/_layouts/mypage.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;Source=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location)"/>